# change typeface of textview in android

Tags: android, textview, typeface

I want to change font of my entire app to roboto-reglar. For that i have used code mentioned in https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin/7749076 link. But only for 1 heading text in my app i want to set font as Arial.I have added below code for that.

```
  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/arial.ttf");
    mHeaderText.setTypeface(tf);
```

But still this heading is displayed in Roboto font. Please help me. I am stuck with this.

Comment: Have you tried getContext().getAssets() ?

Comment: Have you add customized textview or simple textview for heading?

Comment: Are you sure the "arial.ttf" inside the  assets->fonts folder?

Comment: Download a font from internet and put it under assets/fonts folder.

Comment: http://cooltext.com/Download-Font-Rothenburg+Decorative

Comment: Hi All, I have properly added font file and all..it was working fine also.but after adding code to make application font to roboto it s not working